# Start Animation While Button IsPressed in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this `DoubleAnimation` in my XAML that scrolls a `ScrollViewer` up and down depending on a button which is pressed.  I'm trying to switch it to animate (scroll) indefinitely when the button is pressed and stop animating when the button is released.  I cant seem to figure out how to do this in XAML. I'd like to avoid doing this in code because I'm using an MVVM pattern and have been pretty good about separating the UI from the logic.  Here's my animation code

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="ScrollUp">
        <BeginStoryboard HandoffBehavior="Compose">
            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1">
                <DoubleAnimation 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewerView"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(wpf:ScrollViewerBinding.VerticalOffset)" 
                    To="{Binding NewVerticalScrollPositionUp}">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <SineEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="ScrollDown">
        <BeginStoryboard HandoffBehavior="Compose">
            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0:1">
                <DoubleAnimation 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewerView"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(wpf:ScrollViewerBinding.VerticalOffset)" 
                    To="{Binding NewVerticalScrollPositionDown}">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

When I press the down button, it animates, scrolling the `ScrollViewer` down. The same goes for when I press the up button. But I cant figure out a way to make the animation keep going while the button is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RepeatButton` instead of a regular `Button`. A `RepeatButton` functions like the arrow buttons on a `ScrollBar` and continues to fire at a fixed interval for as long as it is pressed.  Note that its `Interval` property is measured in milliseconds.

Comment: You rule! I didn't even know RepeatButton was a thing! After playing around with the timing of the animation and the Interval of the RepeatButton I got it moving pretty smooth. Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new animation which runs continuously and start it on the button press. Then stop the continuous animation on the button release.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to start a continuous animation, or how to stop an animation that's already started.